# Number of page requests by any Bot in 5 secs

Tags: php, security, web-crawlers, botattack

I am writing a script that will block any bot that requests page(s) for example **X**  times in the past **5 secs**. I need to find the X here. Do you guys know some approx values I can use?

Comment: Since I did not get any suggestions, I am setting it to 800 requests in 2 secs. This means my script will block all the bots if there are 800 requests or more in the past 2 secs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might be better off using your firewall instead of relying on a php script, since after all the php script will only affect php page loads and not static files like images. Plus, having php log all connections and check for >800 from the same ip for every request is going to add some serious overhead to your server, maybe even more so than the requests themselves!

If you have a linux server you can use IPTables:

http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/prevent-dos-with-iptables/

or you would setup fail2ban to block excessive GETs, you should be safe from blocking real users at a limit of 800/2sec

http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2011/05/fail2ban-protect-web-server-http-dos-attack-1084.html

On Windows Server... well I don't think you can set connections/sec limits, but I think you can set bandwidth quotas in the QoS services which would effectively limit the bots. Or there are plenty of 3rd party tools that would let you accomplish this.

**Edit**

I've been thinking about this some more, and it seems the most efficient way to log each ip request and check previous hits would be to concatenate the ip address & current time as the filename and just append a single character, so you are just incrementing the filesize by 1 byte each request. Here is a test script I wrote that you can play around with to get the general idea:

```
$limit      = 400;
$requests   = 1000;
$log_file   = '/tmp/ip_'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'_'.time();
$ban_file   = '/tmp/ban_'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

for($i = 0; $i < $requests; $i++){
    clearstatcache();
    if(file_exists($ban_file)){
        echo "<h1>you've been banned</h1>"; 
        exit;
    }
    $log = fopen($log_file, "a"); 
    fwrite($log,'0');
    fclose($log);       
    if(filesize($log_file) > $limit){
        $log = fopen($ban_file, "w"); 
        fwrite($log,NULL);
        fclose($log);
    }
    else{
        echo filesize($log_file).'<br/>';
    }
}
echo 'final '.filesize($log_file).'<br/>';
```

Run this with $requests < $limits and you'll see everything is fine no matter how many times you refresh. Change $requests > $limits and you'll see it stops once the filesize reaches 401 bytes. Refresh again and you'll see now you are instantly banned!

 It is important to have the clearstatcache(); before each file checks, otherwise PHP will cache the initial filesize and file_exists results and keep reporting as 1 byte & file doesnt exist and never exceed your limit or see the ban file. Also you will need to run a cronjob script periodically to delete the old ip counter files so they don't fill up too much space.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. The request table only has about max 80 rows at any given time. The script above has 800 set so that I want to trigger the condition only if there really is a need for it. I am hosting a site elsewhere and cant really play with the firewall. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The problem here is that you can't really have peristant vars across requests. You could with a session but a bot is likely to ignore your session cookie, making each request appear as a new client. Writing to a database or flat file 400+times per second AND checking that file every requests is a lot of work! If you do go the MySQL route, set your storage engine to MEMORY so it will use a ram storage instead of writing to the harddrive since you need speed and dont need permanent storage across reboots

Comment: can you modify the apache conf files? If so, take a look at the limitipconn mod mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248982/how-to-limit-connections-for-user to cut down the number of requests. And then add a usleep(100000) at the top of each page to make each request delay 1/10th of a second - not enough for your visitors to notice but enough to slow down a bot requesting a page every 1/400 of a second.

Comment: added test code for you to play around with, let me know if that works in the real world if you do use it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great code. I have modified it in such a way that it will ban anything without a session for 1 whole hour if this trap is activated. I am calling this the Extreme Flood Trap. I know I will be banning even the good bots which leads me to my next question. **Will serving the Searchbots with 403 for an hour have bad consequences for the site in the long run?** Here is the code so far -

```
$limit      = 400;
$log_file   = 'ip_'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'_'.time();
$ban_file   = 'ban_'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

clearstatcache();
if(file_exists($ban_file)){  
    $banlimit = file_get_contents($ban_file)+3600; 
    if(time() < $banlimit){
        if (!tep_session_id()) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

//creats a file and addes 1 byte of data on each page request
$log = fopen($log_file, "a"); 
fwrite($log,'0');
fclose($log);    

//if the size of the log file is greater than the Request limit size then create a ban file
if(filesize($log_file) > $limit){
    $log = fopen($ban_file, "w"); 
    fwrite($log,time());
    fclose($log);
}
```

What do you think?? bad choice??

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

`4xx (client errors) - 
Google treats all 4xx errors in the same way and assumes that no valid robots.txt file exists. It is assumed that there are no restrictions. This is a "full allow" for crawling. Note: this includes 401 "Unauthorized" and 403 "Forbidden" HTTP result codes.`

Comment: Good use of time() in the ban file for a temporary ban, I was going to suggest that then I saw you already implemented it. For Google, you can create a google webmaster account and control the crawl rate of your site in order to not get hammered. Pretty sure bing and yahoo have similar tools. I don't think session is necessary since a real user will not hammer your site like this and it would mean the ban would be ineffective against a bot that did use sessions

Comment: Also I noticed you removed the folder path from ip and ban files, You should have a set folder location for these, otherwise unless you use a framework with a bootstrap file (ie all pages flow through /index.php?page=), it will scatter the ip files in the different directories where your pages are which would make them ineffective.

Comment: Actually I just pasted the test code on here. I would be using more refined codes for real implementation. I wanted this script only for bots without sessions as I have a number of other scripts that will protect my site for those conditions. Thanks for your help. This has been an educational thread.

Comment: no problem my friend. I enjoy a good challenge, and I might just need to add something like this to my own site one day.